# How to create a graph from an object with all the node data?

Tags: javascript, json, graph, dijkstra

I have to make a routeplanner for tram- and metrolines for a schoolproject. I have been given this piece of code that processes 19 JSON files with tram- and metroline data. This includes things like stop name, stop location, etc.

```
/**
 * ImportMap is a function that read the content from a URL and expects JSON in return.
 * It then hands over the content to the function processMap to actually process its content
 * 
 * @param {*} fileName 
 */

function importMap (fileName) {

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = fileName;

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            processMapInfo(myArr);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

/**
 * Reads the line information and updates the internal map structure
 * @param {*} lineData (JSON string as object)
 */
function processMapInfo (lineData) {
    listOfLines.push(lineData)

    var mainItem;
    var networkItem;
    var networkItemStop;
    var listOfStops = {}; // declared as associative array

    for (mainItem in lineData) {
        logInfo (mainItem,LOG_DETAILS);
        // There should be only 1 mainItem that starts with something like "GVB_"
        // We need this to access the other information

        /* First read the transportation type and its id */
        typeOfTransportation = lineData[mainItem]["Line"].TransportType;
        idOfTransportation = lineData[mainItem]["Line"].LinePublicNumber;

        for (networkItem in lineData[mainItem]["Network"]) {
            // usually there are 1 or 2 networkItems that each represent a list of network stops
            for (networkItemStop in lineData[mainItem]["Network"][networkItem]) {
                // scan all stops
                // add a stop to a list based on its order; this is described by UserStopOrderNumber
                // but only when it does not exist already
                if (!listOfStops.hasOwnProperty(lineData[mainItem]["Network"][networkItem][networkItemStop].UserStopOrderNumber)) {
                    listOfStops [lineData[mainItem]["Network"][networkItem][networkItemStop].UserStopOrderNumber] = 
                        lineData[mainItem]["Network"][networkItem][networkItemStop].TimingPointName;
                }
            }
        }
    }   
    logInfo (listOfStops,LOG_DETAILS);

    // listOfStops now has all the info to update your map structure :-)
}

/**
 * We need a way to check that ALL imports have finished as this is a ASYNCHRONOUS process
 * @param {*} expectedNumberOfFiles 
 */
function checkImport (expectedNumberOfFiles) {
    console.log(listOfLines);

    if (listOfLines.length == expectedNumberOfFiles) {
        clearTimeout ();


        // etc... all JSON files have been processed ... do your thing :-)
    }
}

importMap ("./JSON_files/GVB_1_1.json");
importMap ("./JSON_files/GVB_2_1.json");
importMap ("./JSON_files/GVB_3_1.json");
importMap ("./JSON_files/GVB_4_1.json");
importMap ("./JSON_files/GVB_5_1.json");
importMap ("./JSON_files/GVB_7_1.json");
importMap ("./JSON_files/GVB_11_1.json");
importMap ("./JSON_files/GVB_12_1.json");
importMap ("./JSON_files/GVB_13_1.json");
importMap ("./JSON_files/GVB_14_1.json");
importMap ("./JSON_files/GVB_17_1.json");
importMap ("./JSON_files/GVB_19_1.json");
importMap ("./JSON_files/GVB_24_1.json");
importMap ("./JSON_files/GVB_26_1.json");
importMap ("./JSON_files/GVB_50_1.json");
importMap ("./JSON_files/GVB_51_1.json");
importMap ("./JSON_files/GVB_52_1.json");
importMap ("./JSON_files/GVB_53_1.json");
importMap ("./JSON_files/GVB_54_1.json");


// add a short wait so we know ALL 19 lines have been processed
setTimeout (checkImport (19),1000);
```

To be honest, I have no clue what this code exactly does and how it does it. But I think the listOfStops contains all the stops and this function puts them into this variable.

For the routeplanner I have to use Dijktra's algorithm. But before I can use the algorithm I need a graph that contains all the stops as nodes and adds the edges. I found some information online, but they were manually creating the nodes and edges. As there are a lot of stops I was looking for a way to create the graph from the (I think) listOfStops array. I found some possible solutions online, but they use external libraries or frameworks. My school decided that I need to make everything myself, so no external libraries of frameworks can be used. This got rid of all these sollutions.

What I am looking for is any possible help to at least create the graph. I have no clue how to do this and couldn't find anything on google or on stackoverflow.

This is one of the files that contains line info: https://ori.clow.nl/algds/GVB_1_1.json

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is the goal of your project to find the shortest route between two locations, taking into account switching lines? In this case, there may be no need for Djikstra because the distance is fixed for each route (so you simply need to follow the route), and in general only one line services a location (unless switching).

Comment: To build your graph, you will need to create a set of nodes. Each node should have a TimingPointName (the station), as well as the following station (eg: NextTimingPointName, which is the next node in your set). Each node also needs to have the time it takes to reach the next node (given by subtracting the source TimingPointCode from the destination TimingPointCode).

Since it looks like the expected output should be a list of stops, it would be helpful to include additional detail in the node (eg: line id/name), so that you can indicate switching lines.

Comment: Here is an example of a node:
{
  name: 'station-1',
  neighbors: [
    {timeCost: 10, node: {/** station 2 node */} },
    {timeCost: 20, node: {/** station 3 node */} }
  ]
}